# Outlook does not save sent mail in "sent items folder" although the "save copies" setting is enabled

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, sent-items

In Outlook 2013 I have configured

- several Exchange accounts
- **two POP3** accounts (saved in in PST files)

**Problem:**

**One of the POP3 accounts** stopped suddenly saving sent mails in the `"sent items folder"`. (In the other account the sent mails are still saved correctly)

---

This global setting is set:

[image]

---

**Edit1**
There are no group policies in use which affect the outlook settings.

---

Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to give a read to this [Microsoft Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2958272/email-sent-using-outlook-are-not-saved-to-the-sent-items-folder). It might help you out

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This document does not solve may problem. The "save copies" setting is enabled and there are no group policies affecting Outlook.